# How to create rpm for a python project

Tags: python, rpm, rpmbuild

I have a python project, that does have a setup.py file. Now I am able to create an rpm using `python setup.py bdist_rpm`. I installed the several python dependencies using pip. Now when I take the resulted rpm to another machine/host, I am getting several python package related error, like:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'enum34<2,>=1.0.4' distribution was not found and is required by xyz
```

Anybody has any idea how to resolve this issue?
Is using `bdist_rpm` is the best way to create rpm out of a python project? Should I use something else to statically bind all the dependencies in the rpm itself?

Edit: Adding setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import codecs
import os
import re
import sys

from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup


def read(*parts):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *parts)
    with codecs.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
        return fobj.read()


def find_version(*file_paths):
    version_file = read(*file_paths)
    version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]",
                              version_file, re.M)
    if version_match:
        return version_match.group(1)
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")


install_requires = [
    'cached-property >= 1.2.0, < 2',
    'docopt >= 0.6.1, < 0.7',
    'PyYAML >= 3.10, < 4',
    'requests >= 2.6.1, < 2.8',
    'texttable >= 0.8.1, < 0.9',
    'websocket-client >= 0.32.0, < 1.0',
    'docker-py >= 1.8.1, < 2',
    'dockerpty >= 0.4.1, < 0.5',
    'six >= 1.3.0, < 2',
    'jsonschema >= 2.5.1, < 3',
]


tests_require = [
    'pytest',
]


if sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 4):
    tests_require.append('mock >= 1.0.1')
    install_requires.append('enum34 >= 1.0.4, < 2')


setup(
    name='docker-compose',
    version=find_version("compose", "__init__.py"),
    description='Multi-container orchestration for Docker',
    url='https://www.docker.com/',
    author='Docker, Inc.',
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests.*', 'tests']),
    include_package_data=True,
    test_suite='nose.collector',
    install_requires=install_requires,
    tests_require=tests_require,
    entry_points="""
    [console_scripts]
    docker-compose=compose.cli.main:main
    """,
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    ],
)
```

Comment: maybe you should post the contents of your setup.py file; because that doesn't look very good.

Comment: @ChrisMaes I have edited the question.

Comment: how are you installing the created rpm? using `rpm`, `zypper` or something else? I think all that message is saying is: you have dependencies that are not installed; so you have to make sure they get installed. If you use zypper with the correct repositories; zypper will take care of that for you. (or `yum` )

Comment: I am using yum, those dependencies were install using pip, does yum take care of that?

Comment: I think yum does not know about the "packages" you installed using pip.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, that's what I want to know, what's the other way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116050/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-pensu).

Answer (score 1):

Jordan Sissel's [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) project is really handy for making RPM/DEB from a bunch of different source types, python included. Take a look at the [wiki page for python](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/ConvertingPython) for some instructions on this.  It's pretty good at handling dependencies for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want the dependencies to be installed statically, so that I don't have to do it again on the next machine. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I did have a little hack on this earlier (https://gist.github.com/boyvinall/1349b056c6d1c730ae1ffe440d5aa918) but was trickier than I thought. I wouldn't bundle everything into a single rpm but to ensure that required dependent packages are also available so that they get installed when you install this one.  Make sure that you use the same package names as provided by your distro.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you pyp2rpm for generating python packages.

Staticaly linked modules -- that is called bundling and it is bad. You will regret it sooner or later. If you want to use dependencies which are not in distribution, you can use https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/copr/PyPI2/
which contains lots of PyPI modules packaged as RPM.

Comment: looks nice, not seen that before :)